# Match two columns resulting in a third of longer length

Tags: r, match

I have two `data.frame`s:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,2,3,4), Birth.date = c("2015-09-16","2015-09-17","2015-09-18","2015-09-19"))

df2 <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), value = c("a","b","c","d","e","a","b","c"))
```

Goal is to add a `Birth.date` column to `df2`, so that each row shows the birth date of each `ID` from `df1`. Resulting in looking like this:

```
Goal <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4), value = c(a,b,c,d,e,a,b,c)), Birth.date = c("2015-09-16","2015-09-16","2015-09-17","2015-09-17","2015-09-18","2015-09-18","2015-09-19","2015-09-19"))
```

I tried using `match()` but it gave this:

```
df2$Birth.Date <- df1[match(df1$ID, df2$ID),2]

df2

  ID value Birth.Date
1  1     a 2015-09-16
2  1     b 2015-09-18
3  2     c       <NA>
4  2     d       <NA>
5  3     e 2015-09-16
6  3     a 2015-09-18
7  4     b       <NA>
8  4     c       <NA>
```

Been trying to figure it out for a while now but to no avail. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `left_join`

```
library(dplyr)
left_join(df2, df1, by = "ID")
#     ID value Birth.date
#1  1     a 2015-09-16
#2  1     b 2015-09-16
#3  2     c 2015-09-17
#4  2     d 2015-09-17
#5  3     e 2015-09-18
#6  3     a 2015-09-18
#7  4     b 2015-09-19
#8  4     c 2015-09-19
```

---

If we are using `match`, the correct option would be to have `x` as the 'ID' from 'df2' and `table` with 'ID' from 'df1'

```
df2$Birth.date <- df1$Birth.date[match(df2$ID, df1$ID)]
```

Comment: Thank you! The `match` correction worked but `left_join` did not with my actual data - error says: index out of bounds. I'm assuming with it having something to do with having 5 columns in `df1` instead of 2?

Comment: @Bonono I am not sure about the error.  It should have worked as we are joining by 'ID'.

Comment: I found where the problem was - I'd forgotten to have the column named `ID` in both `df`s

Comment: @Bonono It is not need to have the same column name, `left_join(df2, df2, by = c("ID2" = "ID1"))` if 'ID1' and 'ID2' are the column names in df1, df2.

Answer (score 1):

Using `merge` from base R:

```
> merge(df2,df1,by.x = 'ID')

  ID value Birth.date
1  1     a 2015-09-16
2  1     b 2015-09-16
3  2     c 2015-09-17
4  2     d 2015-09-17
5  3     e 2015-09-18
6  3     a 2015-09-18
7  4     b 2015-09-19
8  4     c 2015-09-19
```